# Rviz doesn't recieve kinect streams from turtlebot

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do SLAM-mapping using a Turtlebot. The kinect works, but RVIZ doesn't recieve any data from it. I have the following errors:

error 1 (in dashboard):

Node: /rviz_1326231834235022764
Time: 1326233463.821563932
Severity: Warn
Location: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:MessageFilter::checkFailures:481
Published Topics: /rosout, /initialpose, /move_base_simple/goal

MessageFilter [target=/map ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

error 2 (in rviz):
Camerainfo

No camerainfo recieved on camera/depth/camera_info]. Topic may not exist.

Error 3 Sometimes I get this error in dashboard:

Node: /openni_manager
Time: 1326234101.630842089
Severity: Warn
Location: /tmp/buildd/ros-electric-openni-kinect-0.3.2/debian/ros-electric-openni-kinect/opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/openni_camera/src/nodelets/openni_nodelet.cpp:OpenNINodelet::subscriberChangedEvent:352
Published Topics: /rosout, /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed, /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed/parameter_updates, /camera/rgb/image_color, /camera/rgb/image_color/theora, /camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_descriptions, /camera/rgb/image_color/theora/parameter_updates, /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed, /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /camera/rgb/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates, /camera/rgb/image_raw, /camera/rgb/image_raw/theora, /camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions, /camera/rgb/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates, /camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed, /camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /camera/rgb/image_mono/compressed/parameter_updates, /camera/rgb/image_mono, /camera/rgb/image_mono/theora, /camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_descriptions, /camera/rgb/image_mono/theora/parameter_updates, /camera/depth/image/compressed, /camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /camera/depth/image/compressed/parameter_updates, /camera/depth/image, /camera/depth/image/theora, /camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_descriptions, /camera/depth/image/theora/parameter_updates, /camera/depth/image_raw/compressed, /camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions, /camera/depth/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates, /camera/depth/image_raw, /camera/depth/image_raw/theora, /camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions, /camera/depth/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates, /camera/depth/disparity, /camera/rgb/camera_info, /camera/depth/camera_info, /camera/depth/points, /camera/rgb/points, /openni_camera/parameter_descriptions, /openni_camera/parameter_updates, /openni_manager/bond, /narrow_scan, /kinect_laser_narrow/parameter_descriptions, /kinect_laser_narrow/parameter_updates, /cloud_throttled, /scan, /kinect_laser/parameter_descriptions, /kinect_laser/parameter_updates

Camera Info for rgb stream has subscribers, but stream has stopped.

Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12584/rviz-doesn%27t-recieve-kinect-streams-from-turtlebot/) by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Apparently I messed around with rviz settings too much. After I set fixed_frame to /base_link and target Frame to  in .Global Options, everything worked as expected. You can set the options in the rviz window or in .rviz/config and .rviz/display_config.

---

Originally posted by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) with karma: 41 on 2012-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a message version mismatch between the computer running rviz and the turtlebot. Are you running the same version of ROS on both?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) on 2012-01-11**:
Thanks, that worked! I'll put it an answer below. Thanks for your great help!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-01-11**:
This could also be a problem with your choice of coordinate frames in rviz. If your fixed or target frame isn't valid, rviz will fail to find a transform from the the camera frame to your target frame, so it displays nothing. Try choosing a different frames.

**Comment by [Robert Buzink](https://answers.ros.org/users/1627/robert-buzink/) on 2012-01-11**:
Thanks for the suggestion! But I am running electric on ubuntu 11.10 on both master and slave.